# how to open a pdf file and preview it in a form using pdfsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Can I open a pdf file and have a preview of it in a form? I am going to make an application that draws line in the pdf like paint and I want to have it rendered to a pdf. I have tried searching about it here and I cannot find any answers... I am using PDFsharp.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is an application, not on web.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I should be careful!

Comment: You want to have a PDF rendered to a PDF? PDFsharp creates and modifies PDF files, but does not render them.

Comment: @User241.007 I found a sample from migradocs which is document preview, but it is using .mdddl extension in opening documents. is there a way i could have conversion from .pdf to .mdddl? im still new in pdfsharp and migradoc... i am still needing samples to understand... found it here.. https://github.com/DavidS/MigraDoc/tree/master/MigraDoc/samples/Samples%20C%23/Based%20on%20GDI%2B/DocumentViewer

Comment: PDFsharp cannot render PDF. MigraDoc cannot render PDF. If you don't believe me, at least read the FAQ: http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Can_PDFsharp_show_PDF_files_Print_PDF_files_Create_images_from_PDF_files_3

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp does not render PDF files.

You need a different library to render PDF files to images or forms.

PDFsharp can draw lines on existing PDF files. You will need a third-party viewer or renderer for PDF files.